# MySQL Database compatibility with MySQL

Tags: mysql

would my presumption be correct, that any MySQL 5.0.x database is compatible with any MySQL 5.0.x system?

I ask as I am seriously considering wiping my server and starting afresh with Debian instead of RHEL5.

I have a db which is 5.0.77, and would like to put it into a Debian system with 5.0.51a on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most MySQL backup guides will have you use mysqldump, which generally dumps your data out to text files which you then re-import (as SQL statements that you run) to restore.  Even if the binary table format changes between versions (and you can use MyISAM tables, InnoDB tables, etc), you are dealing at a higher level of abstraction to that and you don't have to worry.

The main thing to note when migrating between different versions is character set compatibility.  Be sure your tables are created with the same default character set on the destination server as the source.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much, sqldumped and ready for import!

Answer (score 0):

I've been loading mysqldumps from my laptop on 5.1.37:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib **5.1.37**, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using  EditLine wrapper
```

into a hosted vm:

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib **5.0.32**, for pc-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.2
```

for a couple of months now without having any problems.  So I'm guessing you should be ok.   Maybe you can restore a dump into a test database and point your app at that to check it out?

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much, I'm not as nervous about changing now, thanks.